# Remove Facebook OAuth hash with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Facebook likes to add `#_=_` to the end of the OAuth callback URL we give it.  While we're not using hash-based navigation, it looks annoying and I'd like to get rid of it.

`location.hash = '';` causes an infinite loop in `$watch` (this also happens with `$window.location.hash = '';`).  The Angular way of `$location.hash('');` changes nothing.  `$location.path('');` gets us part of the way there, resulting in `/#/` being appended to our url.

I've also played around with `$locationProvider.html5Mode` and received nothing but errors.  (`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $locationProviderProvider <- $locationProvider`
) though this may be my own fault.

How can I remove the OAuth hash without error?

Comment: The Angular error about `Unknown provider` could be caused by you not having ngRoute installed, which split onto it's own file a couple versions ago.

Comment: Where in your code are putting the `$locationProvider.html5Mode()` setter?

Comment: $location.hash('') seems to be successfully removing the hash for me. Are you calling it from outside of Angular loop? If so, you should call $scope.$apply for this to take effect.

Comment: Not sure why this question is attracting downvotes...

Answer (score 2):

Similar to how the *search* property needs to begin with *?*, the *hash* property should begin with *#*.

Instead of setting location.hash equal to an empty string, set it to '#'.

```
location.hash = '#';
```

P.S.

You might be getting down votes due to this

> While we're not using hash-based navigation, it looks annoying and I'd like to get rid of it.

Although I have no qualms about this, a question is a question regardless of the reason, some might find it a waste of time since the only perceived reason is that you find it annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=...&redirect_uri=... OAuth call. In my code, I provide them an URI encoded redirect URI that already includes a hash such as myserver.com/myapp/#/login/facebook, so their redirect will be handled within the AngularJS $routeProvider of my app. Strangely, Facebook attaches an '&' to the path after the hash, so my $routeProvider config looks like

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/login/facebook', {
    templateUrl: 'dialogs/login/facebook.html',
    controller: 'LoginFacebookCtrl'
  }).
  when('/login/facebook&', { // Facebook seems to attach an & at the end
    templateUrl: 'dialogs/login/facebook.html',
    controller: 'LoginFacebookCtrl'
  })
  ...
}]);
```

Works for me.

Comment: I'm not using `ng-route` in this project.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with FB, but we do a fair amount of URL processing using Angular's http [interceptors](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors). You can implement a simple regex replace on incoming data this way (adapted from the docs):

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return {
        'response': function(response) {
            // alter the response
            var loc = response.headers.location;
            response.headers.location = loc.replace(/#_=_$/,'');

            // pass along the altered response
            return response;
        }
    };
});
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

This goes in a `.config` module of your angular app. It will run transparently under ALL requests via the $http service, so you may want to do additional processing if you need to leave some URLs alone.

Comment: Close, but not a valid solution - this is a page load problem, not an `$http` problem.

Comment: is there an example of this that I could look at. Would love to help but I'm not sure what mechanism is providing the URL (redirect, data request, etc.) and how you want to use it (rewrite to a more 'rest' style url, display, etc.).

Comment: You are missing return statement before 'response' key declaration

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a redirection if it would be suitable for you:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/_=_', { redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

Comment: The backend doesn't see the hash on requests.

Comment: Who's talking about the backend? That's a frontend code actually.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that Angular changes `#_=_` into `#/_=_`, so we can reset it with `$location.path('/')`.

This will result in `/#/` which is a usual hashbang which we can turn off by using [html5 mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider).

```
myApp.config(['$locationProvider',
    function ($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

You will need to add `<base href="/">` tag under `<head>` section according to its [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase).