# Node.js is keeping URL hash after response.redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-oauth

I've seen many JavaScript fixes for this using `window.location`, but nothing for Node.js.

I'm using OAuth to connect users to Facebook. Upon authorization, Facebook redirects to your callback URL and appends "#*=*" to it. The problem is in my callback route I redirect to another URL, but the URL fragment (hash) is being carried over.

This is my route for Facebook's callback:

```
exports.facebook_signin_complete = function(req, res)
{
    res.redirect('/profile');
};
```

If I remove the redirect the URL is `/auth/facebook/callback#_=_`, and if I keep the redirect the URL is `/profile#_=_`. Why is the hash being carried over? That's a page specific anchor marker, so I'd be very surprised if that's what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

The hash in a URL is client-side only, so you can't modify it from the server side of things.  [When I ran into the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21561795/1216976) I ended up just adding `window.location.hash = '';` to the top of my initial JS file.